# Simple file reader throwing "String index out of range: -1" error

Tags: file, indexing, filereader

Im working on a program that will read a text file containing a name and some numbers after it. Every time I try to find something it will give me the index out of range error! The text contains the student name, then a comma between the name and each number.

```
public class GradingQuizes   
{  
   final static String inResponses = "responses.txt";  
   final static String inKey = "key.txt";  
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  
{  

    Scanner responses;
    Scanner answerKey;

    File resp = new File(inResponses);
    responses = new Scanner(resp);
    File xkey = new File(inKey);
    answerKey = new Scanner(xkey);

    String line = " ";

    ArrayList<Student> myClass = new ArrayList<Student>();
    while (responses.hasNextLine())
    {
        int firstComma = line.indexOf(",");
        String studentName = line.substring(0, firstComma);
        System.out.println(studentName);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: you should hav a string[] and split the each line on the comma!

Comment: Where should I add the string?

Comment: you need to split the line on the comma